# Hadoop: key and value are tab separated in the output file. how to do it semicolon-separated?

Tags: dictionary, hadoop, mapreduce, reduce

I think the title is already explaining my question. I would like to change

```
key (tab space) value
```

into

```
key;value
```

in all output files the reducers are generating from the output of mappers.

I could not find good documentation on this using google. Can anyone please give a fraction of code on how to achieve this?

Comment: what version (0.20.2, 0.20.20x, 1.0.x, 2.0.0?) and distro (Apache, Cloudera?) of hadoop are you using

Comment: What are you using as your Output format class: `o.a.h.mapred.TextOutputFormat`, or `o.a.h.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat`?

Answer (score 19):

Set the configuration property `mapred.textoutputformat.separator` to `";"`

Comment: it should be mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator if you are using the new API

Comment: 1.0.0 still shows `mapred.textoutputformat.separator` in its source for `o.a.h.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat` - http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/tags/release-1.0.0/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/TextOutputFormat.java?view=markup, line 115

Comment: MR2 (YARN), this has changed to `mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator`

Comment: I am using 1.0.2 hadoop version. can't find the specified path. how can I import it to my java code?

Comment: Specified path for what, import what?

Comment: I am expecting something like org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator; or is this configuration xml configuration file based?

Comment: It's a configuration property, set it on your JobConf or Job object (depending on whether you're using the old mapred or new mapreduce API)

Comment: @Chris: please look at this, new API does not seem to support the property. http://lucene.472066.n3.nabble.com/How-to-set-up-output-field-separator-td3722639.html

Comment: lets be clear about what we mean by new vs old API. If you're using anything prior to hadoop 2 (YARN), then it's `mapred.textoutputformat.separator` irrespective to whether you're using `o.a.h.mapred.TextOutputFormat` or `o.a.h.mapreduce.lib.output.TextOutputFormat`, otherwise with 2+ (YARN) it's `mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator` irrespective to whatever version of TextOutputFormat you're using. For Cloudera based releases, prior to v4 its `mapred.textoutputformat.separator`, v4+ it's `mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator`

Comment: Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator",";");
is this correct way of specifying? Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    conf.set("*mapred.textoutputformat.separator*",";"); did not work.

Comment: Give me some more context around this line of code. Are you using JobConf or Job? Change your code to either jobConf.set(...) or job.getConfiguration().set(...) depending on which API you're using

Comment: Configuration conf = new Configuration(); conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator",";"); worked! Thx, without the *s around the parameter. Thx!

Comment: In Cloudera [CDH4.3.0 (mr1)](https://repository.cloudera.com/content/groups/public/org/apache/hadoop/hadoop-core/2.0.0-mr1-cdh4.3.0-SNAPSHOT/), it is `mapred.textoutputformat.separator` (I just decompiled the JAR to check, since no sources JAR is provided).

Answer (score 16):

In lack of better documentation, here's what I've collected:

```
    setTextOutputFormatSeparator(final Job job, final String separator){
            final Configuration conf = job.getConfiguration(); //ensure accurate config ref

            conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", separator); //Prior to Hadoop 2 (YARN)
            conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", separator);  //Hadoop v2+ (YARN)
            conf.set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator", separator);
            conf.set("mapreduce.output.key.field.separator", separator);
            conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separatorText", separator); // ?
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use "KEY_VALUE_SEPERATOR " property of "KeyValueLineRecordReader" to specify a separator of your choice.

Comment: This property can be set when reading the data back in, but isn't used for output