# Hadoop - output key/value separator

Tags: java, hadoop, separator

I want to change the Output Separator to ; instead of tab. I already tried:
[Hadoop: key and value are tab separated in the output file. how to do it semicolon-separated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031785/hadoop-key-and-value-are-tab-separated-in-the-output-file-how-to-do-it-semicol)
but still my Output ist

```
key (tab) value
```

I'm using the Cloudera Demo (CDH 4.1.3).
Here is my Code:

```
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
            System.err.println("Usage: Driver <in> <out>");
            System.exit(2);
        }
        conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", ";");

        Path in = new Path(otherArgs[0]);
        Path out = new Path(otherArgs[1]);

        Job job= new Job(getConf());
        job.setJobName("MapReduce");

        job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
        job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

        job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
        job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

        job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
        job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```

I want

```
key;value
```

as my output.

Comment: See this : http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/can-we-change-default-key-value-output.html

Answer (score 9):

The property is called `mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator`.
So you are basically missing the `output` there.

You can see that in the newest trunk source code [found in the Apache SVN.](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/TextOutputFormat.java?view=markup)

Comment: @JustTheAverageGirl = Hadoop 2.0 aka YARN (which is the default in CDH4) has replaced a lot of the mapred.* properties with mapreduce.*

Comment: @ChrisWhite the `mapreduce` properties just denote the newer API which should replace the old `mapred` one. Nowadays, both are still usable and none is deprecated. Just wanted to clarify that `mapreduce` is no sign for Hadoop 2.0 or YARN (I guess you know ;)).

Comment: Yes, but i was pointing out that this property has changes between v1 [line 115 - http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/branches/branch-1.2/src/mapred/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/TextOutputFormat.java?view=markup] and v2 [line 45 - http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/hadoop/common/trunk/hadoop-mapreduce-project/hadoop-mapreduce-client/hadoop-mapreduce-client-core/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/lib/output/TextOutputFormat.java?view=markup] - same class, different property to set the prefix

Comment: I tried mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator but still no ; as separator.

Comment: @JustTheAverageGirl then you should ask the Cloudera support what the property is called in their distribution.

Comment: @ThomasJungblut: It is conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ";"); instead of conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", ";"); . mapred and mapreduce played the game.

Answer (score 5):

You should `conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", ";");`

Use of `conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", ";");`  is deprecated

`mapred` and `mapreduce`

[Link](http://www.unmeshasreeveni.blogspot.in/2014/04/can-we-change-default-key-value-output.html)

Full code:This is working.

```
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args).getRemainingArgs();
    if (otherArgs.length != 2) {
        System.err.println("Usage: Driver <in> <out>");
        System.exit(2);
    }
    conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ";");

    Path in = new Path(otherArgs[0]);
    Path out = new Path(otherArgs[1]);

    Job job= new Job(getConf());
    job.setJobName("MapReduce");

    job.setMapperClass(Mapper.class);
    job.setReducerClass(Reducer.class);

    job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
    job.setOutputValueClass(Text.class);

    job.setInputFormatClass(TextInputFormat.class);
    job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);

    FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, in);
    FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, out);

    job.setJarByClass(Driver.class);
    job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1;
```

Answer (score 5):

In 2019, it's `getConf().set(TextOutputFormat.SEPARATOR, ";");` (thanks @AsheshKumarSingh)

Using native constant provides better maintainability and less surprise I believe.

Important: this property must be set **before** `Job.getInstance(getConf())` / `new Job(getConf())`, as job copies parameters and doesn't care about further conf modifications.

Comment: The constant is misspelled in the Hadoop code. It's `SEPERATOR` as @Nikita Bosik writes

Comment: As of Oct 2019, its `TextOutputFormat.SEPARATOR`