# Hadoop (Yarn): Set mapper input separator?

Tags: java, hadoop, hadoop2

I want to be able to set different separators for my key/value pairs which I **receive** in to the map function of my MR job.

For example my text file might have:

```
John-23
Mary-45
Scott-13
```

and in my map function I want the key to be John and the value to be 23 etc for each element.

Then if I set the output separator using

```
conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", "-");
```

Will the reducer pick up the key until the first '-' and the value everything after that? or do I need to make changes for the reducer as well?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Reading**

In case you use the `org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.TextInputFormat`, you can simply use a `String#split` in the `Mapper`.

```
 @Override
 public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

     String[] keyValue = value.toString().split("-");
     // would emit John -> 23 as a text
     context.write(new Text(keyValue[0]), new Text(keyValue[1]));
 }
```

**Writing**

In case you output it that way:

```
Text key = new Text("John");
LongWritable value = new LongWritable(23);
// of course key and value can come from the reduce method itself,
// I just want to illustrate the types
context.write(key, value);
```

Yes, the `TextOutputFormat` takes care of writing that in your desired format:

```
John-23
```

The only trap that I came across in Hadoop 2.x (YARN) [and already answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16614029/hadoop-output-key-value-separator) is that the property was renamed to `mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator`.

Comment: What about the mapper though? How can I make sure that the Key and Value given to me in the map method are John and 23 respectively? Thanks

Comment: @Mo. so you are talking about the input, not the output?

Comment: Yes I mean the input.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That would certainly work but is there a way to  let hadoop make the split for us before the data reaches the map function? so that the key argument supplied by the map method is actually ``John`` and the value is ``23``?

Comment: @Mo. I'm pretty sure that you would either find an `InputFormat` for that on the internet or write one yourself. Either way, it probably isn't worth the hassle.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/57440/discussion-between-mo-and-thomas-jungblut).