# Map Reduce output to CSV or do I need Key Values?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, elastic-map-reduce

My map function produces a

`Key\tValue`

Value = List(value1, value2, value3)

then my reduce function produces:

`Key\tCSV-Line`

Ex.

---

2323232-2322    fdsfs,sdfs,dfsfs,0,0,0,2,fsda,3,23,3,s,

2323555-22222    dfasd,sdfas,adfs,0,0,2,0,fasafa,2,23,s

---

Ex. RawData:
`232342|@3423@|34343|sfasdfasdF|433443|Sfasfdas|324343` x 1000

Anyway I want to eliminate the key's at the beginning of that so my client can do a straight import into mysql. I have about 50 data files, my question is after it maps them once and the reducer starts does it need the key printed out with the value or can I just print the value?

---

More information:

Here this code might shine some better light on the situation

http://pastebin.ca/2410217

this is kinda what I plan to do.

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question?Do you want to emit only the values and not the keys?I'm sorry, I didn't quite get it.

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I want haha, sorry for being so unclear. I just want to make sure when I use multiple servers on multiple data files that emitting only the values and not keys in the reduce.py wont break the whole operation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reducer can emit a line without \t, or, in your case, just what you're calling the value. Unfortunately, hadoop streaming will interpret this as a key with a null value and automatically append a delimiter (\t by default) to the end of each line. You can change what this delimiter is but, when I played around with this, I could not get it to not append a delimiter. I don't remember the exact details but based on this ([Hadoop: key and value are tab separated in the output file. how to do it semicolon-separated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031785/hadoop-key-and-value-are-tab-separated-in-the-output-file-how-to-do-it-semicol)) I think the property is mapred.textoutputformat.separator. My solution was to strip the \t at the end of each line as I pulled the file back:

```
hadoop fs -cat hadoopfile | perl -pe 's/\t$//' > destfile
```

Comment: My output looks correct as a CSV file, however you are saying that if my reducer outputs a value without a key it will just make a null key and wont work anyway? I pastied my code maybe you can take a look and see if it will work:
http://pastebin.ca/2410217

Comment: See I don't output any key just the values (csv seperated), but you are saying that this will just cause emr to say its a null key and not work?

Comment: EMR is Elastic Map Reduce from Amazon? I haven't used that. We're running a "vanilla" hadoop cluster which we submit jobs to and pull data down from. In that environment, if your reducer outputs a row that doesn't contain a delimiter, hadoop adds a delimiter to the end of the row. I think it is interpreting the row as a key with a null value. As far as running on EMR, I can't guess. Can you test it with a small dataset? On a side note, looks like you're adding an extra ',' to the end of each row.

Answer (score 13):

If you do not want to emit the key set it to `NullWritable` in your code. For example :

```
public static class TokenCounterReducer extends
            Reducer<Text, IntWritable, NullWritable, IntWritable> {
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<IntWritable> values,
                Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            int sum = 0;
            for (IntWritable value : values) {
                sum += value.get();
            }
            context.write(NullWritable.get(), new IntWritable(sum));
//          context.write(key, new IntWritable(sum));
        }
```

Let me know if this is not what you need, i'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I believe that is using C# or Java by the looks of it, I am currently using python. I will update my question with some code ot make it more obvious :D

Comment: Added some code to maybe help me get this resolved :) http://pastebin.ca/2410217 
Maybe this explains a little better what I am doing, and I want to know if it works haha