# Is map reduce suitable for invoking web services and transforming xml data?

Tags: java, parallel-processing, mapreduce

We have a job that runs on a single node taking up to 40m to complete, and with M/R we hope to get that down to less than 2m, but we're not sure what parts of the process go into `map()` and `reduce()`.

**Current Process:**
For a list of keys, call a web service for each key and get xml response; transform xml into pipe-delimited format; output a single file in the end...

```
def keys = 100..9999
def output = new StringBuffer()
keys.each(){ key -> 
   def xmlResponse = callRemoteService( key)
   def transformed = convertToPipeDelimited( xmlResponse)
   output.append( transformed)
}
file.write( output)
```

**Map/Reduce Model**
Here's how I modeled it with map/reduce, just want to make sure I'm on the right path...

*Mapper*
The keys get pulled from keys.txt; I call the remote service for each key and store key/xml pair...

```
public static class XMLMapper extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {
        private Text xml = new Text();
        public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context){          
           String xmlResponse = callRemoteService( key)
           xml.set( xmlResponse)
           context.write(key, xml);
        }
    }
```

*Reducer*
For each key/xml pair, I transform the xml to pipe-delimited format, then write out the result...

```
public static class XMLToPipeDelimitedReducer extends Reducer<Text,Text,Text,Text> {
        private Text result = new Text();
        public void reduce(Text key, Iterable<Text> values, Context context ) { 
            String xml = values.iterator().next();
            String transformed = convertToPipeDelimited( xml);   
            result.set( transformed);
            context.write( key, result);
        }
    }
```

**Questions**

- Is it good practice to call the web service in `map()` while doing the
  transform in `reduce()`; any benefits from doing both operations in
  `map()`?
- I don't check for duplicates in `reduce()` because keys.txt
  contains no duplicate keys; is that safe?
- How can I control the format of the output file? `TextOutputFormat` looks interesting; I want it to read like this...

> ```
> 100|foo bar|$456,098
> 101|bar foo|$20,980
> ```

Comment: Wouldn't the webservice be the true limiting factor here?

Comment: Assuming there was only one, yes, but it sits behind a proxy where multiple instances are deployed on several nodes.

Answer (score 1):

You should do the transform map-side, for a couple of reasons:

- Turning from xml to pipe-delimited will reduce the amount of data you're serializing and transmitting into the reducer.
- You will be running multiple map jobs, but a single reduce job, so you want to transform map-side to take advantage of that parallelism.
- Since all the work is map-side, you can just use the provided IdentityReducer and not have to write your own code for that.

If you want a single output file, you'll want to use a single reducer; map-reduce produces one output file per reducer.

If you're sure there are no duplicate keys, then yes, it should be safe to ignore duplicates reduce-side.

I believe TextOutputFormat will by default write your (key, value) pairs to file as a tab-separated string, so not quite the format you want. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031785/hadoop-key-and-value-are-tab-separated-in-the-output-file-how-to-do-it-semicol) for how you might change that.

Your webservice is going to be one limiting factor here. Assuming you want your 40-minute job to run in 2 minutes, you'll probably want 40 or so map jobs reading from it. Can it handle 40 concurrent readers?

Your other limiting factor is going to be the reduce-side. Assuming you want a single output file sorted by key, you're going to have to use a single reducer, and it will have to sort all your input, which could take a little bit.

Once you have your code working, you'll have to run some experiments and see what settings give you a reasonable run-time. Good luck.

Comment: The output doesn't have to be sorted. So `map()` is executed in parallel, but `reduce()`, in this case, is not because I need a single output file? How do I configure M/R to use a single reducer?

Comment: Output that passes through a reducer is always sorted. If you need a single output file, you'll have to set a reducer class (even just IdentityReducer), and it defaults to a single reducer instance. That number can be overridden in your driver class on the job configuration.