# Changing MapReduce (K, V) output format

Tags: java, hadoop, io, formatting, output

I am writing a basic hadoop word count function in java and need the output to be formatted as (k: v) rather than the default (k '\t' v). So far I've only found ways to format the input delimiter using KeyValueTextInputFormat (which is deprecated) and there does not seem to be a corresponding version for output format. Is there a simple way to do this?

Comment: What are you trying to format exactly, please elaborate.

Comment: I am trying to format the (k,v) pairs in the hdfs output.

For example running <hadoop fs -cat /user/vince/wordcount/output/part-*> prints a list as (k '\t' v) but instead I want a list as (k: v).


I also edited the question. I didn't realize that inequalities in the post act as comments.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can be achieved by setting this parameter `mapred.textoutputformat.separator` in `configuration` of job to desired delimiter. In your case it will be something like `conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ":");` . Depending on version of hadoop and distribution the parameter name could be different.

Comment: I found more detailed answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031785/hadoop-key-and-value-are-tab-separated-in-the-output-file-how-to-do-it-semicolon