# how to change ouput format of mapreduce in hadoop?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, format, matrix-multiplication

I'm now practicing MapReduce in Hadoop, 
and I got this code of matrix multiplication,
there isn't any question running it, but the [output format](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QIf4I.jpg) is not what I want. I currently have:

```
00    66
01    78
02    90
```

The format I want is like

```
0,0,66
0,1,78
0,2,90
```

How do I change the [code](https://gist.github.com/RenInTw/b833d0c694c804c74b55b45743a1f4d9)?

Comment: You need to change your keys format and add a comma and see this answer to change the delimiter between the key/value - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11031785/hadoop-key-and-value-are-tab-separated-in-the-output-file-how-to-do-it-semicol

Comment: @BinaryNerd
Actually I just can't find where to change the key format..., and I have tried mapred.textoutputformat.separator", "," , mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", ",",
and mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator", ",",
but none of them work.

Comment: So you fixed the delimiter and its just the key that's the problem now?

Comment: @BinaryNerd
no, delimiter isn't fixed either, maybe i should try
 conf.set("mapreduce.output.key.field.separator", separator);
 conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separatorText", separator);
to see if it can fix it
p.s. my hadoop ver. is 2.6

Comment: You need to add `conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", ",");` to your main, as stated in the answer i linked to.

Comment: I've tried `conf.set("mapred.textoutputformat.separator", ","); 
conf.set("mapreduce.textoutputformat.separator", ","); 
conf.set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator", separator);
conf.set("mapreduce.output.key.field.separator", separator);`
But none of them work :(

Comment: @BinaryNerd
I fixed the delimiter, it seems that code has to be added before 
`FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);`, or `Job job = Job.getInstance(conf);`
And for my version(which is 2.6), seems only `conf.set("mapreduce.output.textoutputformat.separator", ",");` work,

But I still can't figure out how to change key problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the format of the key in the Mapper. There are two places where it creates `sKey`. At the moment both lines (56 & 68) that look like:

```
sKey = row+i; (taking line 56 as an example)
```

So you can just change it too:

```
sKey = row+","+i;
```

Which will give you the format you're after.

Comment: I just figured out it about 1 hour ago too.
Much thanks to you!